# How to nextval in prepared statement in Oracle?

Tags: oracle11g, prepared-statement

I am trying to use a prepared statement. Previously my query was as below

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(LPAD(" + name + ".NEXTVAL, " + size + ",'" + prefix + "')) AS NEXTVAL FROM DUAL;
```

But after converting this to prepared statement-->

```
prestmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT TO_CHAR(LPAD(?,?,?)) AS NEXTVAL FROM DUAL");
                prestmt.setString(1,name+".NEXTVAL");
                prestmt.setString(2,size);
                prestmt.setString(3,prefix);
```

But its not giving me the output. The name(which is sequence) is a dynamic value.

Comment: Identifiers (column names, table names, sequence names) can't be used as parameters in a `PreparedStatement`. You have give the sequence name as part of the SQL string.

Comment: so should i write it as: prestmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT TO_CHAR(LPAD(?.nextval,?,?)) AS NEXTVAL FROM DUAL"); prestmt.setString(1,name);prestmt.setString(2,size);               prestmt.setString(3,prefix);

Comment: i have tried as said above but its giving me issue as: Exception occured while get Sequence Values. Exception=java.sql.SQLException: ORA-22806: not an object or REF

Comment: Again: you can **not** use a name (an identifier) as a *parameter*. You need to use `"SELECT TO_CHAR(LPAD(" + name + ".nextval,?,?)) AS NEXTVAL FROM DUAL")`

Comment: It worked.:) Thanks a lot for your help. I really appreciate. You are correct that we cant use Identifiers (column names, table names, sequence names) in preparedstatement as parameters.